# where is the code that executes the template hierarchy?

Tags: template-hierarchy

I can see a picture of the template hierarchy [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy), but where is the actual wordpress code which decides that it's a "category page" or an "archives page" or a "search page"?

Answer (score 3):

`wp-includes/template-loader.php` is the file which *is* the template hierarchy. However, by the time that file executes, all the template decisions are already made since all that file does is check for boolean flags (defined in `wp-includes/query.php` function `init_query_flags`).

So all the heavy-lifting and interesting code happens before that at `wp-settings.php` line 225:

```
$wp_the_query = new WP_Query();
```

and it is definitely inside of the WP_Query class (starting with the constructor in `wp-includes/query.php` line 2998) where all the interesting logic happens.